# I need the max size of my vector (the value I gave) C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following codes:

Fixed sized vector:

```
template <typename T, size_t siz>
struct fixVec : public std::vector<T> {
    void push_back(const T& d) {
    if (std::vector<T>::size() >= siz) throw std::bad_alloc();
    std::vector<T>::push_back(d);
}
};
```

I use "fixVec" like this:

```
ClonableHeteroStore<ClonableTestClass, fixVec<ClonableTestClass*, 1>, MyException> t1;
```

It creates a vector with the size of 1. ***(1)***

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW(t1.add(new ClonableTestClass));
```

It adds 1 element, its fine, no error. ***(2)***

```
EXPECT_THROW(t1.add(new ClonableTestClass), MyException);
```

Here it should throw the exception. ***(3)***

My problem is that: how can I check when I reach the "max_size()" of MY vector. Not the max size of the vector my PC can handle. 
Or how can I get back the value I gave in code ***(1)*** (the number between the !):

```
ClonableHeteroStore<ClonableTestClass, fixVec<ClonableTestClass*, !!!1!!! >, MyException> t1;
```

I have a class named ClonableHeteroStore where I have the following code:

```
template <typename T1, class S, typename PRED = int>
class ClonableHeteroStore 
{
private:
    S flakker;
    size_t currently;
    size_t maxi;
public:
    ClonableHeteroStore() :  { currently = 0; maxi = 0; }

    void add(T1 *rhs)
    {
        if (currently < ???????? )
        {
            flakker.push_back(rhs);
            currently++;
        }
        else
        {
            delete rhs;
            throw PRED();
        }
    }
```

What should it do:
In case we did not reach the maximum size of the vector we gave in code ***(1)*** it should add a new element to the vector. In case we reached the limit we gave in code ***(1)***, it should drop an exception.

So line ***(2)*** won't have any problem because the vector's size is 1 and this is the first element we put in it. The "if" part should run.

Line ***(3)*** will throw an exception because it tries to put a second element, but the vector size is *1*. The "else" part should run.

The only code is possible to change is the ClonableHeteroStore class. Somehow I should find out, how big is my vector. I read alot that vector is dinamically allocating it's size etc. etc., but in this case, it has to throw an exception if I jump over the limit (1).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just add a `static` constant to `fixVec` that is equal to `siz`.

Comment: I can't change that code. I can change only my class' code. (school project, I have to upload only my class to test it online. It won't work there even if on my pc it will).

Comment: In your code `fixVec<ClonableTestClass*, 1>`, the maximum number of elements is 1. If you're going to need that information later, don't throw it away.

Comment: Yeah, but how am I supposed to see this information in my class?

Comment: @Malkalma -- `delete rhs;` -- Why are you destroying the client's data?  If the vector is "full", just say it's full -- don't go and destroy the data sent to your class.  In addition, how do you know that address came about from a call to `new`?  What if the client just gives you the address of a non-dynamically allocated variable?

Comment: Because the task says to do that. If it's full, it has to be deleted or the task won't be good because there gonna be a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

Two common solutions for extracting template arguments from a type are type traits that use partial explicit specialization or to use a function template  to deduce the template arguments from the function argument. The function-based approach consists of writing a function that expects a `fixVec<T, I>` and getting the compiler to deduce `I` :

```
// The compiler will deduce T and I from the argument
template<class T, size_t I>
size_t get_vec_size(const fixVec<T, I> &) {
    return I;
}

void foo()
{
    fixVec<char, 10> my_vec;
    const auto my_vec_max_size = get_vec_size(my_vec);
}
```

To use partial explicit specialization you write a new template and specialize it for the type whose template arguments you need and, again, get the compiler to deduce those arguments for you :

```
template<class T>
struct vec_size {};

template<class T, size_t I>
struct vec_size<fixVec<T, I>> : std::integral_constant<size_t, I> {};

void foo()
{
    fixVec<char, 10> my_vec;
    const auto my_vec_max_size = vec_size<decltype(my_vec)>::value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

You could for example use [template template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

```
template<template<typename, size_t> typename X, typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t get_size(const X<T, N>&) {
    return N;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << get_size(fixVec<int, 5>{}) << std::endl;
}
```

This will not only work for `fixVec` but any template type with a type and a size_t as template arguments!

So for example the following is also valid:

```
get_size(std::array<int, 5>{});
```

Comment: should't `get_size()` take `X` by const reference instead of by value?

Comment: It is looking good for me, but how am I supposed to use this in my code? I mean: maxi = get_size(flakker); ?

Comment: If you're only allowed to use C++11 you can try using `template<typename, size_t> class X` instead of `template<typename, size_t> typename X`. Otherwise you can compile with -std=c++17. The `constexpr` is not required so you can just remove it.

Comment: And since you already have an instance of `S` you can just use `get_size(flakker)`.

Comment: You're welcome! There seem to be some `<>` missing. Try `template<template<typename, size_t> class X, typename T, size_t N>`.

Comment: If that doesn't compile you can fall back to specifying the type manually: `template<typename T, size_t N> size_t get_size(const fixVec<T, N>&) { return N; }`

Comment: Seems like it's working. Thank you very much. For me it's much easier to understand something if I have a working example and I don't have to spend hours on testing/thinking.

Comment: I understand. The example I provided only works with fairly recent compilers.

Comment: @robinleander I got some new problems if you have some time... Did not mention it, but in the class template the second argument is some kind of stl container. The default is vector, but in case the test is about making a std::list, it says no matching function for call to "get_size", but I don't find how should I change the code to work. https://imgur.com/a/4Pkwzqe

Comment: You'll have to put it in some header and include it wherever its needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Fixed sized vector:

Why are you using `std::vector` instead of `std:array` for a "fixed" array?

> It creates a vector with the size of 1. (1)

No, it doesn't.  It creates a `vector` whose `size()` and `capacity()` are initially 0, not 1.  Your `siz` value is being used as an artificial *max capacity*, you are still allowing the vector to grow dynamically until it reaches your max.

> ```
> EXPECT_THROW(t1.add(new ClonableTestClass), MyException);
> ```
>
> Here it should throw the exception. (3)

True, and worse, it leaks the `ClonableTestClass` object as a result.  You should be using `std::unique_ptr<ClonableTestClass>` instead so you maintain ownership of the object at all times and free it correctly, even if an exception is thrown.

> how can I check when I reach the "max_size()" of MY vector.

You already are.  That is exactly what `size() >= siz` is doing.

> Or how can I get back the value I gave in code (1) (the number between the !):
>
> ```
> ClonableHeteroStore<ClonableTestClass, fixVec<ClonableTestClass*, !!!1!!! >, MyException> t1;
> ```

It is only available in the `siz` template parameter.  If you want OUTSIDE code to know the value of `siz`, then you need to expose public access to it, eg:

```
template <typename T, size_t siz>
struct fixVec : public std::vector<T>
{
    const size_t max_elements_allowed;
    fixVec() : max_elements_allowed(siz) {}
    ...
};
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later:

```
template <typename T, size_t siz>
struct fixVec : public std::vector<T>
{
    const size_t max_elements_allowed = siz;
    ...
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
void add(T1 *rhs)
{
    if (currently < flakker.max_elements_allowed)
    {
        flakker.push_back(rhs);
        currently++;
    }
    else
    {
        delete rhs;
        throw PRED();
    }
}
```

FYI, you don't really need `currently`, you could just use `flakker.size()` instead:

```
void add(T1 *rhs)
{
    if (flakker.size() < flakker.max_elements_allowed)
    {
        flakker.push_back(rhs);
    }
    else
    {
        delete rhs;
        throw PRED();
    }
}
```

That said, `std::vector` has a [`capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) method, which is what you are really looking for:

```
void add(T1 *rhs)
{
    if (flakker.size() < flakker.capacity())
    {
        flakker.push_back(rhs);
    }
    else
    {
        delete rhs;
        throw PRED();
    }
}
```

You just need to *pre-allocate* the `vector`'s internal array up front:

```
template <typename T, size_t siz>
struct fixVec : public std::vector<T>
{
    fixVec() { std::vector<T>::reserve(siz); } // <-- add this!
    ...
};
```

> I have a class named ClonableHeteroStore where I have the following code:
>
> ```
> ...
> ```
>
> What should it do: In case we did not reach the maximum size of the vector we gave in code (1) it should add a new element to the vector. In case we reached the limit we gave in code (1), it should drop an exception.

Since your `fixVec` is already handling that, you should just add the element unconditionally and let `push_back()` throw if needed:

```
void add(T1 *rhs)
{
    try
    {
        flakker.push_back(rhs);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        delete rhs;
        throw PRED();
    }
}
```

A better design is to let the caller maintain ownership of the object that is being added and do not release that ownership unless `add()` is successful.  That way, if an exception is thrown, the caller can free the object correctly and not leak it.  That should not be `add()`'s responsibility to handle:

```
void add(T1 *rhs)
{
    try
    {
        flakker.push_back(rhs);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw PRED();
    }
}

...

ClonableTestClass *obj = new ClonableTestClass;
try
{
    t1.add(obj);
}
catch (...)
{
    delete obj;
    throw;
}
```

Or, if you are using C++11 or later:

```
std::unique_ptr<ClonableTestClass> obj(new ClonableTestClass);
t1.add(obj.get());
obj.release();
```

Or:

```
void add(std::unique_ptr<T1> rhs)
{
    try
    {
        flakker.push_back(rhs.get());
        rhs.release();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        throw PRED();
    }
}

...

t1.add(std::unique_ptr<ClonableTestClass>(new ClonableTestClass));
```

> The only code is possible to change is the ClonableHeteroStore class. Somehow I should find out, how big is my vector.

If you can't change `fixVec` to make its `siz` value public, and you must find out its `siz`, then you have to resort to some template trickery, eg:

```
template<typename T, size_t siz>
size_t get_capacity(const fixVec<T, siz> &) { return siz; }

...

void add(T1 *rhs)
{
    if (flakker.size() < get_capacity(flakker))
        flakker.push_back(rhs);
    else
        throw PRED();
}
```

But, this is exactly why STL containers expose standard `size()` and `capacity()` methods, so you don't have to resort to tricks like this.

On the other hand, `ClonableHeteroStore` doesn't really need to know that `siz` value to begin with.  It should just perform the `push_back()` unconditionally and let it throw if needed.

> I read alot that vector is dinamically allocating it's size etc. etc., but in this case, it has to throw an exception if I jump over the limit (1).

You really should be using `std::array` instead of `std::vector`.

If you must use `std::vector`, than you should consider writing a custom `Allocator` for your `vector` to use instead of using the default `Allocator`.  The custom `Allocator` can throw if it is asked to allocate memory for too many elements.  Then you can let `std::vector` behave normally, and not override its `push_back()` at all.

Comment: The author mentioned that they cannot change the fixVec's code.